# Flutter - How do I change the buttons on the last step in the Stepper?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an app that takes the user through four different steps, with each step requiring the user to provide some information. I'm using the Stepper, and I'd like to replace the last step buttons with a custom button. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Is there a way to call a function with the last step Continue button?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Without that evidence it looks like you want us to find documentation or a tutorial or write code for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no property to set / change the button in `Stepper Widget`

You can use [enhance_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/enhance_stepper) package to modify.

```
  Widget buildStepperCustom(BuildContext context) {
    return EnhanceStepper(
        stepIconSize: 30,
        type: _type,
        horizontalTitlePosition: HorizontalTitlePosition.bottom,
        horizontalLinePosition: HorizontalLinePosition.top,
        currentStep: _index,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        steps: tuples.map((e) => EnhanceStep(
          icon: Icon(e.item1, color: Colors.blue, size: 30,),
          state: StepState.values[tuples.indexOf(e)],
          isActive: _index == tuples.indexOf(e),
          title: Text("step ${tuples.indexOf(e)}"),
          subtitle: Text("${e.item2.toString().split(".").last}",),
          content: Text("Content for Step ${tuples.indexOf(e)}"),
        )).toList(),
        onStepCancel: () {
          go(-1);
        },
        onStepContinue: () {
          go(1);
        },
        onStepTapped: (index) {
          ddlog(index);
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
          });
        },
        controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, { VoidCallback? onStepContinue, VoidCallback? onStepCancel }){
          return Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 30,),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: onStepContinue,
                child: Text("Next"),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 8,),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: onStepCancel, 
                child: Text("Back"), 
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a boolean as lastField set to false.

In the step continue and step cancel, I checked to see if the current step was the last one and change the lastField appropriately.

Then you can change the controls builder based on the lastField.

So my on step continue would look like this:

```
onStepContinue: (){
        if(forms[_currentStep].currentState!.validate()){
          _currentStep < 3 ?
          setState((){
            _currentStep += 1;
            if(_currentStep == 3){
              lastField = true;
            }else{
              lastField = false;
            }
          }): null;
        }
        },
```

And my controls builder would look like this:

```
controlsBuilder: (context, details){
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: lastField ? Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: const Text("Submit"), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: buttonPurple, shape: const StadiumBorder()),),
              TextButton(onPressed: details.onStepCancel, child: const Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),))
            ],
          ) : Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: details.onStepContinue, child: const Text("Next"), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: buttonPurple, shape: const StadiumBorder()),),
              TextButton(onPressed: details.onStepCancel, child: const Text("Cancel", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),))
            ],
          )
        );
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I went about it in my controlsBuilder.

```
 controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controls) {
      final isLastStep = _activeStepIndex == stepList().length - 1;
      return Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(60)),
              onPressed: controls.onStepContinue,
              child: (isLastStep)
                  ? TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(60)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          sending = true;
                        });
                        sendData();
                        
                      },
                      child: const Text('Submit',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    )
                  : const Text('Next'),
            ),
          ),
```